# How do I display a spinner in the middle of UI work?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous, spinner

I have the following function on iOS that performs UI work on a TableView, and the challenge is that if it begins to take longer then 0.5sec. a spinner should be displayed to the user so that the screen doesn't look like it froze.

```
func updateForm(with rowItems: [RowItem]) {

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()   // performance tweak.

    let viewControllerName = String.init(describing: self.classForCoder)    // id
    var defaultSection = Form.createSectionWith(tag: viewControllerName, in: form)

    // MARK: - update rows

    let allRows = self.form.allRows

    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    var showSpinner = false

    for (index, item) in rowItems.enumerated() {
        .
        .
        .
        <TableView processing work on 100's of rows>
        .
        .
        .

        // Evaluate our running time for this process loop, and display spinner if we're past a threshold of seconds.
        let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
        if timeElapsed > 0.5 && showSpinner == false {
            showSpinner = true
            self.showActivityIndicator(withStatus: "processing")    // {NEVER GETS DISPLAYED}
        }

    }  // for (index, item) ...
```

Of course, when I make the call to `showActivityIndicator`, it never actually gets displayed.

How can I interrupt and pause the UI work to have the `showActivityIndicator` spinner animation show-up, then let the loop continue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get off the main thread in order to allow the run loop to cycle and the redraw moment to occur. A simple delay after showing the spinner before proceeding with your work will solve the problem. But you will have to reorganize your code to allow for that. The easiest solution is to give up your 0.5 second idea and just show the spinner before starting in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some more important architectural questions that you need to be addressing with that code, but as a solution to the question asked...

before you start processing the data, create a timer with a delay that will load the spinner when it fires

```
let delayInSeconds = 5.0 
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: delayInSeconds, repeats: false){
   //closure that loads the spinner view on top of the current view
}
```

then when the processing activity is complete

```
timer?.invalidate() //cancels the timer if it hasn't fired
```

and then unload the spinner view